# QListView , how to resize to the best fit size?

Tags: c++, linux, qt4

i implemented a new class which inherits QListView , and now i want to modify sizeHint() to calculate the best width for my new listviewer.

First thought is to hook up the insert of model , retrieve max length , but how to ? Or is there any better suggestions ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is you widget in a layout ? Perhaps with a little of code I can help you here ...

Comment: @vrince , i figured out, the best way is to use QFontMetrics() dynamically calculate its width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views should resize based on space allocated by parent layouts and available screen space. After they are sized they should trim/clip text from the model , this way you can  easily switch models and use the same view on any screen. If you size the view based on data from the model , there is no guarantee that the view will fit in the available screen space.

Comment: i wanted no extra space shown and no horizonal slider shown , i think i could iterate all the items and calculate the maximum size , and this function should be incremental calculation